# JQuery Scroll Follow but Horizontally? (Freeze Column)

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using this: http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

for my large HTML table to freeze the headers. I cloned the original table, cut off the body and made only the header implement the "scroll follow" plugin. It works just fine like how it is in the link.

**Now I would like my first column to do the same but "Horizontally"** because my first column goes off the page when I'm scrolling horizontally. I have no problems vertically because of "scroll follow".

I cloned my original table again and have my first column set up but after doing a lot of research, I can't find what I'm looking for. Here is basically my set up:

```
<table>
  //Original large table
</table>

<table>
  //Cloned table of the first column to be (hopefully) "scroll followed" horizontally
</table>

<div id="scroll follow plugin">
  <table>
    //Cloned table with only headers
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm new to all this JQuery, coding, scripts and html stuff so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using tables. Long story short, the plugin you're trying to use doesn't give you the option to scroll horizontally.

If you want your page to scroll horizontally you can use this [plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/).